# How to configure single thread model in spring MVC framework?

Tags: java, spring, servlets

In my MVC framework,I have a controller class. That should be accessed by only one thread at a time.
My class should not implement SingleThreadModel interface or should not use synchronized blocks.
How can I achieve this?

**It seems there is a configuration available in web.xml. Using a tag we can achieve this.Is there any web.xml configuraiton?**

Comment: Why should not implement SingleThreadModel or use synchronized blocks? just wondering.

Comment: It seems there is a configuration available in web.xml. Using a tag we can achieve this.Is there any web.xml configuraiton?

Comment: Similar to [this SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26299343/is-springmvc-works-on-single-thread-model-or-multithread-model)

Comment: this might be helpful (http://www.javalobby.org/articles/thread-safe/)

Answer (score -1):

Configure your web server allowing only one http connection concurrently.

Comment: ...and how does he configure it?

Comment: What is your web server? Tomcat, Jetty, JBoss?

Comment: http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/tomcat-jdbc-connection-pool-configuration-for-production-and-development/

Comment: your answer is not helpfull for the the question(which is not clear too), it should be a comment... check the link http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer